# Present a pixel buffer to a MTKView

Tags: ios, macos, buffer, pixel, metal

Here is my problem : I want to display a pixel buffer that I calculated to a MTKView. I searched for MTLTexture, MTLBuffer and other Metal objects, but I can't find any way to just present a pixel buffer.
Every tutorial I saw are about presenting 3D objects with vertex and fragments shaders.

I think the buffer has to be presented within the `drawInMTKView` function (maybe with the MTLRenderCommandEncoder), but again, I can't find any information about this.

I hope I'm not asking an obvious question.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome!

I recommend you use Core Image for rendering the content of the pixel buffer into the view. This requires the least manual Metal setup.

Setup the `MTKView` and some required objects as follows (assuming you have a view controller and a storyboard setup):

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var metalView: MTKView!

    var device: MTLDevice!
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    var ciContext: CIContext!

    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        self.commandQueue = self.device.makeCommandQueue()

        self.metalView.delegate = self
        self.metalView.device = self.device
        // this allows us to render into the view's drawable
        self.metalView.framebufferOnly = false

        self.ciContext = CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device)
    }

}
```

In the delegate method you use Core Image to transform the pixel buffer to fit the contents of the view (this is a bonus, adapt it to your use case) and render it using the `CIContext`:

```
extension PreviewViewController:  MTKViewDelegate {

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let pixelBuffer = self.pixelBuffer,
              let commandBuffer = self.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return }
        // turn the pixel buffer into a CIImage so we can use Core Image for rendering into the view
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

        // bonus: transform the image to aspect-fit the view's bounds
        let drawableSize = view.drawableSize
        let scaleX = drawableSize.width / image.extent.width
        let scaleY = drawableSize.height / image.extent.height
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)
        let scaledImage = image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
        // center in the view
        let originX = max(drawableSize.width - scaledImage.extent.size.width, 0) / 2
        let originY = max(drawableSize.height - scaledImage.extent.size.height, 0) / 2
        let centeredImage = scaledImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: originX, y: originY))

        // Create a render destination that allows to lazily fetch the target texture
        // which allows the encoder to process all CI commands _before_ the texture is actually available.
        // This gives a nice speed boost because the CPU doesn't need to wait for the GPU to finish
        // before starting to encode the next frame.
        // Also note that we don't pass a command buffer here, because according to Apple:
        // "Rendering to a CIRenderDestination initialized with a commandBuffer requires encoding all
        // the commands to render an image into the specified buffer. This may impact system responsiveness
        // and may result in higher memory usage if the image requires many passes to render."
        let destination = CIRenderDestination(width: Int(drawableSize.width),
                                              height: Int(drawableSize.height),
                                              pixelFormat: view.colorPixelFormat,
                                              commandBuffer: nil,
                                              mtlTextureProvider: { () -> MTLTexture in
                                                  return currentDrawable.texture
                                              })
        // render into the view's drawable
        let _ = try! self.ciContext.startTask(toRender: centeredImage, to: destination)

        // present the drawable
        commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

There is a slightly simpler way for rendering into the drawable texture instead of using `CIRenderDestination`, but this is recommended if you want to achieve high frame rates (see comment).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes so much more sense to write directly in the currentDrawable's texture. That was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures?language=objc.
In this exemple, they show how to render an image to a Metal view, using just a few vertices and a fragment shader to render the texture to a 2D square.
I'll go from there. Not sure if there isn't a better (simpler ?) way to do that. But I guess that's how Metal wants us to do this.